# Change all formulas in a sheet

Tags: excel

I have these formulas for about 100 cells in my sheet:

```
=IF(AND(A11 <> "fr",  C11, C11<J36),J36-C11,0)

=IF(AND(A11 <> "fr", C11>=J36, D11),IF(J11>J37, J11-J37, 0), IF(AND(A11 <> "fr", C11, C11<J36, D11), IF(J11-E11-J37>0, J11-E11-J37, 0), 0))

=IF(A11="fr", 0, IF(AND(C11, D11, J11<J37), J37-J11, 0))
```

Now I want to change all `J36` to `L1` and all `J37` to `L2`

Is there a simple way to do that instead of changing them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Find and Replace with `Match entire cell contents` checked and `Look in: Formulas`.

So, Select the range, go into `Find and Replace`, make your entries and `Replace All.

[image]

Comment: Why match entire cell contents? Then you have to type out the whole formula.